# Proxychains configuration

Tags: networking, resolution, proxy, tor

I have downloaded *proxychains* and configured it to run with tor. I want a chain of 3 or more proxies. 3 will be enough.

The problem is finding proxies that are up and running i just keep getting messages saying denied/timeout could i have a copy of someones proxychains.conf file that is up and working with alive proxies or give me a copy of proxies in the right arrangement i.e

```
socks4/5
https etc   ip        port 

SOCKS5   1.81.97.243  6673             
SOCKS5   1.81.148.187 6673            
SOCKS5   1.81.127.201 6673            
SOCKS5   1.61.149.199 6673            
SOCKS5   95.78.55.48  1080             
SOCKS4   178.54.32.58 50610           
SOCKS5   178.150.156.219 13579                
SOCKS5   95.78.18.183 1080            
SOCKS4   93.85.4.0    52342              
SOCKS5   5.167.238.35 1080            
SOCKS5   95.78.48.149 1080
```

Comment: Take a look at [This](http://sockslist.net/), it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [wiki](http://anonet2.biz/Open%20Proxies).

This is socks5, must be good:

```
202.152.178.241 1080
121.52.210.118  1863
209.160.40.246  993
202.152.178.241 1863
213.132.241.5   1080
65.125.155.90   8080
```

But anyway it is a public junkyard.

You can gather proxies yourself [here](http://spys.ru/proxylist/) and [here](http://www.proxy4free.com/).

Answer (score 0):

You can download proxy chains from site called **hidemyass**.

Here is the link

https://www.hidemyass.com/

There on the bottom there is a link for VPN, there you can choose the options which proxies you want, types of proxies like socks or http and also the proxy with high uptime.